# Separate Terraform state files for each service?

Tags: terraform

I've been following this particular blog post as a guide.

https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa

So I understand the need to have state files per environment but is anyone going the extra length and using a state file per component? For example, we have modules for our application stack. To keep this example simple, let's say I have two modules.

App1 - contains a LAMP stack

App2 - LAMP stack plus rabbitmq and redis

Each environment (dev, uat and prod) would have both app stack. Would you have a state file for each component, giving you 6 state files?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method in the past - I had 3 separate components and 3 different environments. The different components had different rates of change and some dependencies between then so I used a [remote state datasource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to share output variables between them.

The biggest problem with this approach is the management overhead of maintaining the different environments/components.

An alternative could be to use different components in conjuction with [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)

Comment: Still dipping my toes into TF but what type of overheard were you dealing with? I figure in a perfect world it just works and the only time one would need to manage the file manually is when things go bad.

Comment: Sorry, probably not clear enough. I don't mean a processing/technical overhead just a mental "am I working in the correct environment?" overhead. You don't want to think you're doing a quick update on DEV but you're actually working with PROD setup.

Comment: We have 3 environments (scratch, dev, and prod, 2 regions each) and I use a lot of modules which do all the heavy lifting. I have a little bit of TF for each env that sets env specific things (Account ID, where to store the remote state, etc.). That TF calls a module to do the work. While the env specific TF is separated they all call the same module(s) and that's where I have to do most of the code modification. You could use versioned modules in this scenario to help prevent doing work in the wrong env but that would add to the overhead which I'm willing to deal with.